# Force django or the commandline to use python3

Tags: python, django, command-line, pyenv

I installed python 3.4.2 via pyenv and set the global python to 3.4.2.

However when I run the python command from the commandline, I still get the system python(2.7.6).

Presently, I need to run python3 from the commandline to use 3.4.2

Is there a way to force django to use python 3.4.2 since it is on my machine and chosen as the default via pyenv?

or

Is there a way to force the commandline python command to use version 3.4.2?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using? I've not used PyEnv before, but it looks a fairly simple way of adding a different version of Python to your path basically.

Comment: My am using OSX 10.10. The process of installing 3.4.2 through pyenv was pretty straight forward.  I just can not use it with my django app.  or with out using python3 on the commandline. When I try to do a migration i get the following error: from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line and ImportError: No module named django.core.management.  When I looked that up, it lead me to believe djando was not finding 3.4.2.  Then I figured django is probably running 2.7.6 but I installed django using 3.4.2.  So the missing modules are under the 3.4.2 install.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) You can create so called `virtual` python environment where you can have arbitrary python version as default. even more - running pip install inside virtualenv will install packages only to this virtualenv - system python packages won't be changed. It's very easy to use and provides very clear way to solve problem related to having proper python version.

Comment: Thanks Dariusz.  I will try to use virtualenv.  It did appear from the pyenv github that one could install different versions of python and call python from the commandline; and it would use the python selected by pyenv.  It would have been nice to figure out what I was doing wrong.